# How do I optimize my query in MySQL?

Tags: sql, optimization

I need to improve my query, specially the execution time.This is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*,v.type,v.idName,v.name as etapaName,m.name AS manager,
    c.name AS CLIENT, 
    (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)))
    FROM activities a 
    WHERE a.projectid = p.projectid) AS worked, 
    (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)) 
    FROM activities a 
    WHERE a.projectid = p.projectid) AS worked_seconds,
    (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(remain_time)) 
    FROM tasks t 
    WHERE t.projectid = p.projectid) AS remain_time

FROM projects p

INNER JOIN users m
ON p.managerid = m.userid

INNER JOIN clients c
ON p.clientid = c.clientid

INNER JOIN `values` v
ON p.etapa = v.id

WHERE 1 = 1 

ORDER BY idName 

ASC
```

The execution time of this is aprox. 5 sec. If i remove this part: `(SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(remain_time)) FROM tasks t WHERE t.projectid = p.projectid) AS remain_time`
the execution time is reduced to 0.3 sec. Is there a way to get the values of the **remain_time** in order to reduce the exec.time ?

The SQL is invoked from PHP (if this is relevant to any proposed solution).

Comment: Which database is this?

Comment: Im running this code in cpanel->phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need an index on `tasks`.

Try adding this one:

```
create index idx_tasks_projectid_remaintime on tasks(projectid, remain_time);
```

The correlated subquery should just use the index and go much faster.

Comment: @R.T. . . . The OP put the answer in the last paragraph without realizing it.  If a query is too slow, adding an index is a pretty good approach for speeding it up.  But, we'll see if this actually works.

Comment: can you update your answer with the all query ? I want to see where i have to modify my query. Also im not familiar with index. cand you give me more explanation. I would really appreciate. thx

Comment: @Chester:- You can better read any SQL manual and you will understand what indexes are and its significance!

Comment: @GordonLinoff, where should i include your piece of code in my query ? thx

Comment: QUESTION :  How do i execute it in php and get the result  ? because if i put this query in the beginning of mine, and execute. its not working . why ? :D

Comment: @Chester . . . You need to execute this once so there is an index on the table.  It is not part of the query.  It becomes part of the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing the query *as it is written* would give significant performance benefits (see below). But the FIRST QUESTION TO ASK when approaching any optimization is whether you really need to see all the data - there is no filtering of the resultset implemented here. This is a HUGE impact on how you optimize a query.

Adding an index on the query above will only help if the optimizer is opening a new cursor on the tasks table for *every* row returned by the main query. In the absence of any filtering, it will be *much* faster to do a full table scan of the tasks table.

```
SELECT ilv.*, remaining.rtime
FROM (
  SELECT p.*,v.type, v.idName, v.name as etapaName,
    m.name AS manager, c.name AS CLIENT,
    SEC_TO_TIME(asbq.worked) AS worked, asbq.worked AS seconds_worked,
    FROM projects p
    INNER JOIN users m
       ON p.managerid = m.userid
    INNER JOIN clients c
       ON p.clientid = c.clientid
    INNER JOIN `values` v
       ON p.etapa = v.id
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT a.projectid, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)) AS worked
       FROM activities a 
       GROUP BY a.projectid
    ) asbq
       ON asbq.projectid=p.projectid
  ) ilv
  LEFT JOIN (
     (SELECT t.project_id, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(remain_time)) as rtime
       FROM tasks t 
       GROUP BY t.projectid) remaining
  ON ilv.projectid=remaining.projectid
```

Comment: thx for helping me out, you have two syntax errors . after when i get rid of them , i get this message error: Duplicate column name 'type'

Comment: Set an alias for v.type in the asbq sub query